# Minesweeper clone in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner, game, minesweeper

This was my first attempt at writing object-oriented JavaScript. It's a Minesweeper clone in jQuery. I thought I had done an OK job, but I've just received some feedback stating that it wasn't written in an object-oriented manner. I don't expect anyone to read this line for line.  I'm just looking for general feedback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Minesweeper = function() {
            var self = this;
            var defaultOptions = {
                boardSize: [8, 8],
                difficulty: 'easy'
            }
            // initialize our cell object
            var cells;
            this.init = function(options) {
                // empty the cell object if it has anything in it
                cells = [];
                if (typeof options == 'object') {
                    options = $.extend(defaultOptions, options);
                } else {
                    options = defaultOptions;
                }
                self.difficulty = options.difficulty;
                // setup a new game
                self.newGame(options.boardSize);
            };
            this.newGame = function(boardSize) {
                //remove the old board if there is one, detach event listeners as well
                $('#minesweeper').empty();
                var x = boardSize[0];
                var y = boardSize[1];
                self.width = x;
                //setup our new board
                self.addUI();
                self.buildGrid(x, y);
            }
            this.addUI = function() {
                var board = $('#minesweeper');
                var checkMe = $('<div/>').attr({
                    id: 'check-me',
                    class: 'happy-smiley'
                });
                var mineCount = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'mine-count');
                var timer = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'timer').html('0');
                var ui = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'ui');
                ui.append(mineCount);
                ui.append(timer);
                ui.append(checkMe);
                board.append(ui);
            }
            this.buildGrid = function(columns, rows) {
                var rowDiv;
                var id = 0;
                // build a containg div for each row, and then populate each row with the correct
                // number of cells to fill out our grid
                for (var i = 0; i <= rows - 1; i++) {
                    rowDiv = $('<div/>').attr({
                        'id': 'row' + i,
                        'class': 'row'
                    }).appendTo($('#minesweeper'));
                    for (var j = 0; j <= columns - 1; j++) {
                        var cell = $('<div/>').attr({
                            'id': id++,
                            'class': 'cell'
                        }).appendTo(rowDiv);
                        // add the cell to the cells array so we can access it later instead of 
                        // looping through the DOM
                        cells.push({
                            'hasMine': false,
                            'flagged': false,
                            'cleared': false
                        });
                    }
                }
                // set the width and height of our minesweeper container based on how many columns we have 
                var cellWidth = $('.cell').outerWidth();
                var uiHeight = $('#ui').outerHeight();
                $('#minesweeper').width(cellWidth * columns).height(cellWidth * rows + uiHeight);
                $('.cell').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                // add event listeners for our newly created cells
                self.setHandlers();
                // add the mines to our grid 
                self.setMines(self.difficulty);
            }
            this.setMines = function(difficulty) {
                // the number of mines is different for each difficulty level
                switch (difficulty) {
                case 'hard':
                    var mineDensity = 4;
                    break;
                case 'middle':
                    var mineDensity = 5.2;
                    break;
                default:
                    var mineDensity = 6.4;
                    break;
                }
                var numberOfCells = cells.length;
                var maxCellId = numberOfCells - 1;
                var numberOfMines = Math.round(numberOfCells / mineDensity);
                self.mineCount = numberOfMines;
                $('#mine-count').html(numberOfMines);
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfMines; i++) {
                    // generate a random number between 0 and the maximum cell id we have
                    var cellId = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxCellId) + 1;
                    // check if we have already placed a mine on this cell
                    // if we have, deincrement the counter to make sure we get the correct number of mines
                    if (cells[cellId].hasMine) {
                        i--;
                    } else {
                        // place mine
                        cells[cellId].hasMine = true;
                        $('#' + cellId).addClass('mine');
                    }
                }
            }
            this.setHandlers = function() {
                var firstClick = true;
                $('.cell').on('click', function() {
                    //start the timer only on the first click
                    if (firstClick) {
                        self.startTimer();
                        firstClick = false;
                    }
                    var id = this.id;
                    if (cells[id].hasMine) {
                        self.gameOver();
                        $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
                    } else {
                        self.clearCell(id);
                    }
                });
                $('.cell').on('contextmenu', function(event) {
                    var cell = $(this);
                    var id = this.id;
                    if (cells[id].flagged) {
                        cell.removeClass('flagged');
                        cells[id].flagged = false;
                        cells[id].checked = false;
                        self.mineCount++;
                        $('#mine-count').html(self.mineCount);
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        if (cells[id].cleared) {
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            cell.addClass('flagged');
                            cells[id].flagged = true;
                            self.mineCount = self.mineCount - 1;
                            $('#mine-count').html(self.mineCount);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
                $('#check-me').on('click', function() {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('sad-smiley')) {
                        self.reset();
                    } else {
                        self.check();
                    }
                });
            }
            this.gameOver = function() {
                $('.cell').css('cursor', 'default');
                $('#minesweeper .mine').toggleClass('show');
                $('#check-me').attr('class', 'sad-smiley');
                //lock the game board so the user can't click on any cells 
                $('.cell').off();
                self.stopTimer = true;
            }
            this.cheat = function() {
                $('.mine').toggleClass('show');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.mine').toggleClass('show');
                }, 1000);
            }
            this.reset = function() {
                self.init();
            }
            this.check = function() {
                var loser;
                $.each(cells, function(index) {
                    if (cells[index].cleared == false && cells[index].hasMine == false) {
                        self.gameOver();
                        alert('Looks like you missed a few...');
                        loser = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if (!loser) {
                    self.win();
                }
            }
            this.win = function() {
                $('#check-me').attr('class', 'cool-smiley');
                alert("Winner!")
            }
            this.getNeighbors = function(cellId) {
                var neighbors = new Array();
                var neighborBombs = 0;
                var width = self.width;
                // need to fix this. It was just a hack to make sure we had an integer not a string
                var id = +cellId;
                // If we are on the top row, the id - width will always be < 0
                if (id - width > 0) {
                    // We are not on the top row. So get the cell above us (Top)
                    var top = id - width;
                    neighbors.push(top);
                    if (cells[top].hasMine) {
                        neighborBombs += 1;
                    }
                    // before we get the Top Right cell, check that we aren't on the far right edge of the board
                    if (((top + 1) % width) !== 0) {
                        var topRight = top + 1;
                        neighbors.push(topRight);
                        if (cells[topRight].hasMine) {
                            neighborBombs += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    // do the same with the Top Left cell
                    if ((top % width) !== 0) {
                        var topLeft = top - 1;
                        neighbors.push(topLeft);
                        if (cells[topLeft].hasMine) {
                            neighborBombs += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if the cell id is evenly divisble by the width, then we are on the left edge
                if (id % width !== 0) {
                    var left = id - 1;
                    neighbors.push(left);
                    if (cells[left].hasMine) {
                        neighborBombs += 1;
                    }
                }
                // if the cell id + 1 is evenly divisible by the width, then we are on the right edge
                if ((id + 1) % width !== 0) {
                    var right = id + 1;
                    neighbors.push(right);
                    if (cells[right].hasMine) {
                        neighborBombs += 1;
                    }
                }
                // if the cell id + the width of the grid is < the total number of cells, we are not on the bottom row
                if (id + width < cells.length) {
                    var bottom = id + width;
                    neighbors.push(bottom);
                    if (cells[bottom].hasMine) {
                        neighborBombs += 1;
                    }
                    // check that we aren't on the right edge of the board
                    if ((bottom + 1) % width !== 0) {
                        var bottomRight = bottom + 1;
                        neighbors.push(bottomRight);
                        if (cells[bottomRight].hasMine) {
                            neighborBombs += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    // check that we aren't on the left edge of the board
                    if (bottom % width != 0) {
                        var bottomLeft = bottom - 1;
                        neighbors.push(bottomLeft);
                        if (cells[bottomLeft].hasMine) {
                            neighborBombs += 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
                var cellData = {
                    cells: neighbors,
                    bombs: neighborBombs
                }
                return cellData;
            }
            this.startTimer = function() {
                self.stopTimer = null;
                var time = 0;
                $('#timer').html(time);
                (function tick() {
                    if (self.stopTimer) {
                        clearTimeout(moreTime);
                    } else {
                        time += 1;
                        $('#timer').html(time);
                        var moreTime = setTimeout(tick, 1000);
                    }
                })();
            }
            this.clearCell = function(cellId) {
                if (cells[cellId].checked) {
                    // been here before...
                } else {
                    // make sure there isn't flag on this cell before we clear it
                    if (cells[cellId].flagged == false) {
                        $('#' + cellId).addClass('cleared');
                        cells[cellId].checked = true;
                        cells[cellId].cleared = true;
                        var neighbors = self.getNeighbors(cellId);
                        if (neighbors.bombs > 0) {
                            $('#' + cellId).html(neighbors.bombs);
                            $('#' + cellId).addClass("number" + neighbors.bombs);
                        } else {
                            $('#' + cellId).addClass('cleared');
                            $.each(neighbors.cells, function(index, value) {
                                if (cells[value].hasMine) {} else {
                                    self.clearCell(value);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        cells[cellId].checked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    var minesweeper = new Minesweeper();
    minesweeper.init({
        boardSize: [8, 8],
        difficulty: 'easy'
    });
    // add event listeners for the options panel
    $('#cheat').on('click', function() {
        console.log('cheated');
        minesweeper.cheat();
    });
    $('#new-game').on('click', function() {
        minesweeper.reset();
        minesweeper.stopTimer = true;
    });
    $('#difficulty').change(function() {
        minesweeper.init({
            'difficulty': $(this).val()
        });
    });
    $('#board-size').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
        var x = selected.data('x');
        var y = selected.data('y');
        minesweeper.init({
            boardSize: [x, y]
        });
    })
    $('#show-timer').change(function() {
        $('#timer').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
$(window).load(function() {
    //preload images that will be needed later
    $.fn.preload = function() {
        this.each(function() {
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        });
    }
    $(['/images/mine.png', '/images/red_flag.png', '/images/smiley_cool.png', '/images/smiley_happy.png', '/images/smiley_sad.png']).preload();
});
```

Any thoughts or improvements? Other feedback I have received was that my `getNeighbors` method was too complicated (which it probably is), but I was purposefully trying not to use a coordinate type system. My mistake, I guess.

Comment: Your entire program is pretty much in one function, try separating it into objects and methods. Also the usage of `self` is confusing, the language already has the perfectly fine keyword `this`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I used self in order to access 'this' inside of the method calls, but maybe it's not necessary. Relevant SO question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309516/when-to-use-self-in-javascript.

Comment: Just saw your other comment. Thanks for the helpful feedback.

Comment: I see, well try to identify the objects in your program. The physical entities or abstract concepts. I can recognize plenty of objects here:  `Cell`, `Board`, `Game`, `Grid`, `Mine`, `Timer` and so on. Then design their methods and interactions with each other, and model them with classes (constructors and prototypes). Don't just cram everything inside one function because I have to scroll horizontally because the indentation level is so much out of control.

Answer (score 5):

As @Esailija has said in the comments, OOP is about, well, *objects*.

**Before you write any code**, you should stop and think - what are the key concepts at play here? This is a *Minesweeper* implementation, so the very first thing you should do is lay down all the objects you can think of, what their respective members might be, and how they're all related.

**As you write your code**, you should keep an eye out for objects and methods that *do too many things*. For your code to be simple, each building block must also be fairly simple, i.e. if an object *owns* too much of the functionality, part of it can probably be broken down into simpler objects.

**After you implemented an object**, don't just move on to the next one: re-read your code, refactor repeating or redundant code into smaller reusable functions, lookout for *cyclomatic complexity* (e.g. nested ifs / "arrow" code) and review all names involved. Proper naming is just as important as getting the code to work: if it's a pet project you might finish it and then forget it, but in real-world code you're going to have to *maintain* the code, and that means all you've written was about 20% of the time you'll end up spending on that code - the other 80% is *reading your code*. That said your naming looks good :)